# Decoding a JSON that have numeric keys PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

In a PHP project I get a string like:

```
$s = '{1:"perro", 2:"gato", 3:{"other":"stuff"}}'
```

I just want to parse it using:

```
$jotason = json_decode($s, true);
```

But I get nothing.

I think the problem is related to invalid numeric keys in the JSON string [I receive them like that, cannot change the way they are constructed].

I am sure there must be an obvious and stupid way to fix this, but I am totally blind to it. ¿Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: From where you are getting this string? Are you creating or from database?

Comment: I scrap them from third people's js scripts

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you should complain to whoever created the source for not producing valid JSON.
and complain loudly! probably waving something heavy.

in the meantime, this should fix it, except if you have a string containing something like "1234:":

```
$s = preg_replace("/([1-9][0-9]*):/", "\"$1\":", $s);
```

Comment: Thanks Franz! Yes, getting the right documents would be the best option if possible. In the meanwhile I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Let me add: It worked with some small changes because I had other keys like "15:30"  ... but once convinced there is no other way than fixing the json previously, regex is ok. Thx again.